# Based on the response from Login Controller I need to Pass the control to either Admin Controller or Employee Controller in Spring? How can i do this?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am developing a library managment project in spring MVC. My requirement is first I need to go to Login Controller and check whether the credentials entered are for User or Admin.

If the credentials entered are for User then it needs to call User Controller and from there the user flow needs to be done.

If the credentials entered are for admin then it needs to call admin controller.

How can i do it in Spring?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ABC(ModelMap modelMap){
    if(isAdmin){
        return "redirect:mappingInAdminController";
    }else{
        return "redirect:mappingInUserController";
    }
}
```

And then catch the redirect in the other controllers.

If you want to transfer some data from the LoginController to the other ones you can use `RedirectAttributes`